# Protected enum not seen as type, why?

Tags: c++, arduino, protected

I am compiling some code that defines an emun as protected, like this

```
class MPU9250
{
  protected:
    // Set initial input parameters
    enum A_scale
    {
      AFS_2G = 0,
      AFS_4G,
      AFS_8G,
      AFS_16G
    };
}
```

I would like to use that enum in my method like this, this method is now public within the same class

```
void setAccScale(A_scale accScale);
```

However while compiling error saying

```
../../MPU9250.h: In function 'void initMovementDetected()':
../../MPU9250.h:196:7: error: 'MPU9250::A_scale AFS_8G' is protected
       AFS_8G,
       ^
../../nRF52.cpp:49:31: error: within this context
  mpu9250.setAccScale(MPU9250::AFS_8G);
```

Why is this? May I `setAccScale` public?

Thanks

```
class MPU9250
{
  protected:
    // Set initial input parameters
    enum A_scale
    {
      AFS_2G = 0,
      AFS_4G,
      AFS_8G,
      AFS_16G
    };
 public:
       void setAccScale(A_scale accScale);

}
```

EDIT: I found partially the error, there was a variable called `Ascale` as well, I renamed the enum to `A_scale`

Comment: I don't get an error?

Comment: I do, the above one using `gcc-arm-none-eabi/5_2-2015q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++` as compiler

Comment: Have you tried `void setAccScale(MPU9250::Ascale)` ?

Comment: @m.rogalski yes I did, I get this `../../MPU9250.h: In function 'void initMovementDetected()':
../../MPU9250.h:196:7: error: 'MPU9250::A_scale AFS_8G' is protected
       AFS_8G,
       ^
../../nRF52.cpp:49:31: error: within this context
  mpu9250.setAccScale(MPU9250::AFS_8G);`

Comment: I think you want to use this `enum Ascale` publicly and that's why there's an error. I've checked this [here](http://rextester.com/GFJAD75515) and everything is working fine...

Comment: @m.rogalski I see you use `this` is needed? I have updated  the post with some more error info

Comment: In this file `nRF52.cpp` on line `49` you're trying to use `mpu9250.setAccScale` which is a private method and you're trying to use `protected` enum `A_scale`.

Comment: I have moved the method `setAccScale` to public, my call in `nRF52.cpp` is this  `mpu9250.setAccScale(MPU9250::AFS_8G);` and still having the issue with the protected

Comment: Isn't this obvious? Outside of the class, that enum does not exist. Therefore, you can't use it outside the class. setAccScale is used outside the class with an argument that does not exist there. May I ask why you want to make that enum protected? And if you do so, why you still want to use it from the outside? That's not the idea of protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your error :

> ../../MPU9250.h: In function 'void initMovementDetected()':
>   ../../MPU9250.h:196:7: error: 'MPU9250::A_scale AFS_8G' is protected
>          AFS_8G,
>          ^
>   ../../nRF52.cpp:49:31: error: within this context
>     mpu9250.setAccScale(MPU9250::AFS_8G);

And your data structure :

```
class MPU9250
{
protected:
    enum A_scale
    {
      AFS_2G = 0,
      AFS_4G,
      AFS_8G,
      AFS_16G
    };

private:
    void setAccScale(A_Scale);
}
```

I can assume that you're trying to call `MPU9250::setAccScale` from outside of the `MPU9250` class which is impossible because of the accessibility of that function.
Another thing is that you're trying to access enumeration that is `protected subtype` of your `MPU9250`.

For the fix I would suggest making your `A_scale` publicly visible or rewrite this to use `#define`:

**Solution 1 :**

```
// define this in some header
#ifndef AFS_2G
#    define AFS_2G 0
#endif

#ifndef AFS_4G
#    define AFS_4G 1
#endif
// rest of your values ...

//to use this:
mpu9250.SetAccScale(AFS_2G);
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
//declare this enum as public :
class MPU9250
{
public:
    enum A_scale
    {
        AFS_2G = 0,
        AFS_4G = 1
        // rest of your values
    }
};

// to use this:
mpu9250.SetAccScale(MPU9250::A_scale::AFS_2G);
```

Both of the solutions require from you to make a public function `SetAccScale` because as I assume you're setting this scale from outside of `MPU9250` type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a public class if you're gonna use enum outside of that scope. Also, you need an argument in your function and are missing a semi-colon. I am not sure why you are declaring a function inside of a class? But here is your code with those corrections. Hopefully, I was able to help you.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class MPU9250
{
public:
    // Set initial input parameters
    enum Ascale
    {
        AFS_2G = 0,
        AFS_4G,
        AFS_8G,
        AFS_16G
    };
    void setAccScale(Ascale accScale) {
        std::cout << accScale << std::endl;
    } // function needs argument

};// missing semi-colon
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using `MPU9250::A_scale` from outside of this or derived class, make A_scale public.

But since `void setAccScale(A_scale accScale)` is already private, there is no scenario when A_scale need to be used publicly. Could you show exactly where it is called, some more context:

```
../../nRF52.cpp:49:31: error: within this context
  mpu9250.setAccScale(MPU9250::AFS_8G);
```